# How to virtualize a board with QEMU?

Tags: linux, kernel, qemu, embedded, arm

I've got an embedded board based on ARMv7 cpu. I'd like to virtualize its rootfs with qemu, so I could work without hardware.

I made an image of SD card present on board (these are the partitions):

```
Disk wiser.img: 925 MiB, 969932800 bytes, 1894400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x4adee175

Dispositivo      Avvio  Start    Fine Settori  Size Id Tipo
wiser.img1         2048    8191    6144    3M 83 Linux
wiser.img2         8192  532479  524288  256M 83 Linux
wiser.img3       532480 1894399 1361920  665M 83 Linux
```

Parted reports that **p2 and p3** are *ext4*, but first partition seems to be unformatted (could it be the **dtb** file?)

I can mount p2 and p3. P2 is the **rootfs** and P3 contains **data**.

I extracted following informations by logging in SSH to the board:

```
#cat /proc/cmdline
noinitrd init=/etc/preinit root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootwait
```

```
#cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 109.09
Features        : half fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva vfpd32 lpae
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

Hardware        : Freescale i.MX6 Ultralite (Device Tree)
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 0000000000000000
```

```
#cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.4.186 (logic@build) (gcc version 5.4.0 (LEDE GCC 5.4.0 unknown) ) #0 PREEMPT Tue Jul 23 12:55:21 UTC 2019
```

```
#ls -l /dev
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  4 10:53 RS232 -> /dev/ttymxc0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  4 10:53 RS485 -> /dev/ttymxc2
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            60 Jan  4 10:53 bus
crw-r--r--    1 root     root        5,   1 Jan  4 10:53 console
crw-r--r--    1 root     root       10,  63 Jan  4 10:53 cpu_dma_latency
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        1,   7 Jan  4 10:53 full
crw-r--r--    1 root     root       89,   0 Jan  4 10:53 i2c-0
crw-r--r--    1 root     root      251,   0 Jan  4 10:53 iio:device0
crw-r--r--    1 root     root        1,  11 Jan  4 10:53 kmsg
srw-rw-rw-    1 root     root             0 Jan  4 10:53 log
crw-r--r--    1 root     root       10,  60 Jan  4 10:53 memory_bandwidth
brw-r--r--    1 root     root      179,   0 Jan  4 10:53 mmcblk0
brw-r--r--    1 root     root      179,   1 Jan  4 10:53 mmcblk0p1
brw-r--r--    1 root     root      179,   2 Jan  4 10:53 mmcblk0p2
brw-r--r--    1 root     root      179,   3 Jan  4 10:53 mmcblk0p3
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            60 Jan  4 10:53 net
crw-r--r--    1 root     root       10,  62 Jan  4 10:53 network_latency
crw-r--r--    1 root     root       10,  61 Jan  4 10:53 network_throughput
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        1,   3 Jan  4 10:53 null
crw-r--r--    1 root     root      108,   0 Jan  4 10:53 ppp
crw-r--r--    1 root     root      253,   0 Jan  4 10:53 pps0
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        5,   2 Jan  4 11:09 ptmx
crw-r--r--    1 root     root      252,   0 Jan  4 10:53 ptp0
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 pts
crw-r--r--    1 root     root        1,   8 Jan  4 10:53 random
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            14 Jan  4 10:53 root -> /dev/mmcblk0p2
crw-r--r--    1 root     root      254,   0 Jan  4 10:53 rtc0
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            60 Jan  4 10:54 shm
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        5,   0 Jan  4 10:53 tty
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root      207,  16 Jan  4 10:53 ttymxc0
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root      207,  18 Jan  4 10:53 ttymxc2
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root      207,  21 Jan  4 11:09 ttymxc5
crw-r--r--    1 root     root        1,   9 Jan  4 10:53 urandom
crw-r--r--    1 root     root       10, 130 Jan  4 10:53 watchdog
crw-r--r--    1 root     root      250,   0 Jan  4 10:53 watchdog0
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        1,   5 Jan  4 10:53 zero
```

```
#cat /proc/mounts
/dev/root on / type ext3 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,nodelalloc,stripe=512,data=ordered)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,noatime,size=4096k,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noatime,mode=600,ptmxmode=000)
/dev/mmcblk0p3 on /data type ext3 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,nodelalloc,stripe=512,data=ordered)
```

**This is Kernel boot**

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.4.186 (logic@build) (gcc version 5.4.0 (LEDE GCC 5.4.0 unknown) ) #0 PREEMPT Tue Jul 23 12:55:21 UTC 2019
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fc075] revision 5 (ARMv7), cr=10c53c7d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] Machine model: i.MX6UL LM2i
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writeback
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 65536
[    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c043a910, node_mem_map cfdfb000
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 512 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 65536 pages, LIFO batch:15
[    0.000000] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s0 r0 d32768 u32768 alloc=1*32768
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 65024
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: noinitrd init=/etc/preinit root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootwait
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 255148K/262144K available (3530K kernel code, 114K rwdata, 576K rodata, 164K init, 196K bss, 6996K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
[    0.000000]     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
[    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
[    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0xd0800000 - 0xff800000   ( 752 MB)
[    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xd0000000   ( 256 MB)
[    0.000000]     modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xc0000000   (  16 MB)
[    0.000000]       .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc040adec   (4108 kB)
[    0.000000]       .init : 0xc040b000 - 0xc0434000   ( 164 kB)
[    0.000000]       .data : 0xc0434000 - 0xc0450bb4   ( 115 kB)
[    0.000000]        .bss : 0xc0450bb4 - 0xc0481f08   ( 197 kB)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16
[    0.000000] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 41ns
[    0.000015] sched_clock: 32 bits at 24MHz, resolution 41ns, wraps every 89478484971ns
[    0.000054] clocksource: mxc_timer1: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 79635851949 ns
[    0.001887] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 48.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=96000)
[    0.001921] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.002113] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.002137] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.003081] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.003505] Setting up static identity map for 0x80008200 - 0x80008234
[    0.018724] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 2 part 30 variant 7 rev 5
[    0.019276] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    0.019325] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes)
[    0.019465] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.021334] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.021962] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.081148] imx6ul-pinctrl 20e0000.iomuxc: initialized IMX pinctrl driver
[    0.119456] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.119639] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[    0.120312] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.120477] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.122018] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.126805] i2c i2c-0: IMX I2C adapter registered
[    0.126853] i2c i2c-0: can't use DMA
[    0.127519] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.127548] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.127718] PTP clock support registered
[    0.130596] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    0.131191] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    0.131219] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    0.131258] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    0.131283] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    0.131996] clocksource: Switched to clocksource mxc_timer1
[    0.136438] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.137960] TCP established hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.138038] TCP bind hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.138101] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 2048 bind 2048)
[    0.138214] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.138260] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.138534] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.172592] jffs2: version 2.2. (NAND) © 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
[    0.182122] io scheduler noop registered (default)
[    0.189112] imx-sdma 20ec000.sdma: Timeout waiting for CH0 ready
[    0.189178] imx-sdma 20ec000.sdma: loaded firmware 3.3
[    0.205195] 2020000.serial: ttymxc0 at MMIO 0x2020000 (irq = 19, base_baud = 5000000) is a IMX
[    0.206714] 21ec000.serial: ttymxc2 at MMIO 0x21ec000 (irq = 224, base_baud = 5000000) is a IMX
[    0.207936] 21fc000.serial: ttymxc5 at MMIO 0x21fc000 (irq = 225, base_baud = 5000000) is a IMX
[    0.213557] fsl-quadspi 21e0000.qspi: unrecognized JEDEC id bytes: ff, ff, ff
[    0.213603] fsl-quadspi 21e0000.qspi: Freescale QuadSPI probe failed
[    0.213728] fsl-quadspi: probe of 21e0000.qspi failed with error -2
[    0.215091] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    0.215124] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
[    0.215449] CAN device driver interface
[    0.219083] 2188000.ethernet supply phy not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.232986] pps pps0: new PPS source ptp0
[    0.234004] libphy: fec_enet_mii_bus: probed
[    0.236601] fec 2188000.ethernet eth0: registered PHC device 0
[    0.237063] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[    0.237608] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.237933] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[    0.237960] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[    0.238275] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    0.238784] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[    0.239037] usbcore: registered new interface driver ch341
[    0.239288] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for ch341-uart
[    0.239527] usbcore: registered new interface driver cp210x
[    0.239762] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for cp210x
[    0.240148] usbcore: registered new interface driver ftdi_sio
[    0.241140] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
[    0.241748] usbcore: registered new interface driver mct_u232
[    0.242152] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for MCT U232
[    0.242413] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[    0.243026] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
[    0.243746] usbcore: registered new interface driver pl2303
[    0.244245] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for pl2303
[    0.249455] 2184000.usb supply vbus not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.253640] ci_hdrc ci_hdrc.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.253738] ci_hdrc ci_hdrc.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.264061] ci_hdrc ci_hdrc.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    0.264413] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.264450] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.264477] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.264501] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.4.186 ehci_hcd
[    0.264523] usb usb1: SerialNumber: ci_hdrc.0
[    0.265862] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.265984] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    0.266890] 2184200.usb supply vbus not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.270672] ci_hdrc ci_hdrc.1: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.270767] ci_hdrc ci_hdrc.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    0.280066] ci_hdrc ci_hdrc.1: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    0.280404] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.280437] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.280463] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.280486] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.4.186 ehci_hcd
[    0.280509] usb usb2: SerialNumber: ci_hdrc.1
[    0.281827] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.281931] hub 2-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    0.286852] rtc-pcf85263a 0-0051: rtc core: registered rtc-pcf85263a as rtc0
[    0.287090] i2c /dev entries driver
[    0.287757] lirc_dev: IR Remote Control driver registered, major 249 
[    0.289044] imx2-wdt 20bc000.wdog: timeout 60 sec (nowayout=0)
[    0.289824] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    0.290745] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.290772] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    0.290788] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    0.293645] sdhci-esdhc-imx 2194000.usdhc: No vmmc regulator found
[    0.293685] sdhci-esdhc-imx 2194000.usdhc: No vqmmc regulator found
[    0.332091] mmc0: SDHCI controller on 2194000.usdhc [2194000.usdhc] using ADMA
[    0.353317] 2198000.adc supply vref not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.365315] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[    0.365432] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    0.365473] can: controller area network core (rev 20120528 abi 9)
[    0.365632] NET: Registered protocol family 29
[    0.365655] can: raw protocol (rev 20120528)
[    0.370930] rtc-pcf85263a 0-0051: setting system clock to 2021-01-04 09:53:27 UTC (1609754007)
[    0.371412] vdd3p0: disabling
[    0.371725] Warning: unable to open an initial console.
[    0.371780] Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk0p2...
[    0.387604] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    0.394277] mmc0: new high speed SD card at address 0260
[    0.395033] mmcblk0: mmc0:0260 HSQ01 925 MiB 
[    0.396663]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 p3
[    0.548554] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): recovery complete
[    0.551981] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    0.552094] VFS: Mounted root (ext3 filesystem) on device 179:2.
[    0.552441] Freeing unused kernel memory: 164K
[    0.943923] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: nodelalloc
[    1.368261] fec 2188000.ethernet eth0: Freescale FEC PHY driver [SMSC LAN8710/LAN8720] (mii_bus:phy_addr=2188000.ethernet-1:00, irq=-1)
[    2.418232] fec 2188000.ethernet eth0: Freescale FEC PHY driver [SMSC LAN8710/LAN8720] (mii_bus:phy_addr=2188000.ethernet-1:00, irq=-1)
[    2.636217] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: nodelalloc
[    5.432387] fec 2188000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control off
[   20.192037] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
```

The rootfs based on OpenWrt, so I downloaded armvirt 32bit kernel and imx6 kernel but I don't understand how to run right kernel on qemu mounting the rootfs inside started machine.

Comment: Could you provide a the commands (`qemu-system-arm` and arguments) you have tried?  Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/49930882/1541203 or https://gist.github.com/luk6xff/9f8d2520530a823944355e59343eadc1 helps.